# Connect to the CloudSQL Postgres from different project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, vpc-peering

I'm going to connect from the instance in Project-A(custom VPC) with CloudSQL Postgres in Project-B(default VPC). Documentation says that I need to peer these two VPC. The peering status in the "Active" state. In Project-A I also have cloudsql_auth_proxy. Once I execute cloudsql_auth_proxy, I get this:

```
root@cloudsql-auth-proxy:~# ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=projectB:us-west1:postgres=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432

2022/12/29 16:46:59 current FDs rlimit set to 1048576, wanted limit is 8500. Nothing to do here.

2022/12/29 16:47:01 Listening on 0.0.0.0:5432 for -instances=projectB:us-west1:postgres=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432

2022/12/29 16:47:01 Ready for new connections

2022/12/29 16:47:01 Generated RSA key in 244.541948ms
```

When I try to connect to the cloudsql_proxy like this psql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -U proxyuser -d postgres it hangs.

The output of cloudsql_auth_proxy looks like this:

```
2022/12/29 16:48:00 New connection for "-instances=projectB:us-west1:postgres"

2022/12/29 16:48:00 refreshing ephemeral certificate for instance -instances=projectB:us-west1:postgres

2022/12/29 16:48:00 Scheduling refresh of ephemeral certificate in 55m0s
: dial tcp 10.35.144.3:3307: connect: connection timed out
```

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: You can't connect to a Cloud SQL instace by using a VPC peering. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72171009/can-cloud-sql-proxy-connect-a-vm-and-instance-on-different-vpcs/72177992#72177992

Comment: Non transitive VPC peering make the link impossible. Use a shared VPC or..... a VPN (to peer the 2 VPC), yes, a VPN...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to deploy a Socks5 proxy in Project B VPC to provide a network path between VPCs. Dante is a popular choice.

Once you have a Socks5 proxy running, you can launch the Proxy pointing at it.

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy#running-behind-a-socks5-proxy.

Comment: So basicaly I'm trying to configure Datastream to enable streaming data from CloudSQL to the BigQuery.

Our CloudSQL instance in the project-A, Datastream in the project -B.
Project-A has vpc-A which is peered with vpc-B in the Project-B.
vpc-A has cloudsql_auth proxy and I'm able to ping or login to this database via cloudsql_auth_proxy using psql from VPC-B(Project-B) but I'm not able to connect to the cloudsql_auth_proxy from the Datastream. I need to be able to connect Datastream(Project-A) to the CloudSQL(Project-B) using private connection
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking at cross VPC CloudSQL traffic in 2023, look at PSC for CoudSQL - only works with Mysql and Postgres**

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/private-service-connect-with-managed-databases

---

I think you might have posted this on the GCP subreddit too! :P

To expand on @enocom answer with some diagrams.

For reference :
[image: potatoes-are-great-they-dont-care-about-transitivity]

1. VPC non-transitivity in GCP makes this a bit awkward.
2. I am a bit puzzled by a GCP design that would require running two extra GCE constructs + a socks proxy + a cloud_sql_auth proxy. That's a lot of bits to interconnect GCP native services like CloudSQL and Datastream.
3. I don't think I can remove any of the current pieces. If we remove vm-002, Datastream won't be able to reach vm-001 due to the lack of transitivity.

Reference Dante config to remove the authentication from the socks proxy. Don't do this in prod - just for the sake of simple test ;)

1. In `/etc/danted.conf`
2. systemctl restart danted.service
3. systemctl status danted.service

```
logoutput: syslog
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: none


# The listening network interface or address.
internal: 0.0.0.0 port=1080

# The proxying network interface or address.
external: ens4

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you for the response, I appreciate your help. I did everything as this diagram shows and when I run `ALL_PROXY=socks5://10.138.0.13:1080 ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=mega-project-34522:us-west1:datastream-test=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credentials_file=credentials.json` 

I got this errors

`2023/01/13 20:30:44 couldn't connect to "mega-project-34522:us-west1:datastream-test": socks connect tcp 10.138.0.13:1080->10.35.144.3:3307: no acceptable authentication methods`

Comment: Ah yes, you can remove the authentication layer from Dante to test it out. I added a config snippet in the main post.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much, I appreciate your help! I was stuck on this projectfor 2 weeks...

Comment: No problem! VPC transitivity and GCP native services interconnections is a bit challenging.

Comment: I'm considering to deploy danted5 on kubernetes in project A. I already have docker image. I want to deploy this image but i don't know how to expose it like static private IP address to use it in cloudsql_auth_proxy in project B

Comment: I would look at PSC connectors for CloudSQL.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/private-service-connect-with-managed-databases